# How to set a default increment/decrement value in Java

Tags: java

OK so I have an issue with a homework problem. I'm building a class that be used in a tester class provided by my instructor. Its nothing more than a basic counter. I've got the counter set up to where numbers passed by the tester to my class work fine and output is as expected. However my class must have the initial count set to 0 and a default increment/decrement of 1.

Here is my class:

```
public class Counter
{
    private int count;
    private int stepValue;

    /**
     * This method transfers the values called from CounterTester to instance variables
     * and increases/decreases by the values passed to it. It also returns the value
     * of count. 
     *
     * @param args
     */ 
    public Counter (int initCount, int value)
    {       
        count=initCount;
        stepValue=value;
    }   

    public void increase ()
    {
        count = count + stepValue;
    }

    public void decrease ()
    {
        count = count - stepValue;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

}
```

Here is the tester class:

```
public class CounterTester
{

    /**
     * This program is used to test the Counter class and does not expect any
     * command line arguments. 
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Counter counter = new Counter();

        counter.increase();
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 1 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.increase();
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 2 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.decrease();
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 1 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());


        counter = new Counter(3, 10);
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 3 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.increase();
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 13 ----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.decrease();
        System.out.println("Expected Count: 3 -----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());

        counter.decrease();
        System.out.println("Expected Count: -7 ----> Actual Count: " + counter.getCount());
    }

}
```

Comment: Next time, you may wish to add a question to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a no arg constructor in your Counter class for the first time you instantiate it, so do

```
Counter counter = new Counter(0,1);
```

Which should set the initial and step values.

Or you can provide a no-arg constructor:

```
public class Counter
{
  private int count;
  private int stepValue;

  public Counter () { //no argument constructor - must be explictly made now
    count=0;
    stepValue = 1;
  }

  public Counter (int initCount, int value)
  {       
    count=initCount;
    stepValue=value;
  }  

  //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried this as well, but when compiling, I get the error message that "The constructor Counter() is undefined"
This highlights the "new Counter();" in the Tester class.
I've told my instructor about this and she said that her code is perfect and my code is in error.

Comment: You have to define that constructor as part of your `Counter` class. Normally, if you don't specify a constructor, you get a no-arg one provided by default. This **disappears** when you explictly make one. Therefore in your care, you then have to make a constructor with arguments and one without.

Comment: Ok I just tried your code and it works, but I'm really new to Java and don't understand why I had to create 2 of the same constructors.

Comment: @SkyVar read my explanation in the comment above. And no, they *aren't* the same constructor, they accept different arguments :-)

Comment: I think I understand it now. Because I have 2 constructors (one with args and one without) calling the counter class, I have to have 2 constructors in the counter class.